# how to loop though sub folder to check if folder is empty - batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch

**What I want to do:**

write a batch script to do the following
loop though all dir starting with "01-"...
Check if "Pictures" folder is empty or not. skip rest folders
If "Pictures" folder is Empty, than print path of empty "Pictures" folders.

**Output Example:**

MainFolder/01-Folder3/Pictures is empty

**Structure of my folder:**

1st lvl... Every thing inside my "MainFolder"
2nd lvl... all folders start with a number ex: 01, 02, 03, etc...
3rd lvl... There is folder called "Pictures"... in every 3rd lvl
here is an example:

```
|>MainFolder 
|--->01-Folder1
|------->Pictures
|----------->pic.png
|----------->SubPicFolder
|------->RandomFolder1
|------->RandomFolder2
|--->01-Folder2
|------->Pictures
|----------->SubPicFolder
|------->RandomFolder1
|--->01-Folder3
|------->Pictures
|------->RandomFolder1
|--->02-Folder1
|------->Pictures
|------->RandomFolder1
|------->RandomFolder1
```

**What I have tried?:**

```
@echo off
for /d /r %%A in ("Pictur*") do (
    dir /a /b "%%~fA" 2>nul | findstr "^" >nul || echo %%~fA
)
pause
```

**Problem with what I have tried:**

This code does print all empty "Pictures" folder but issue is that it checks all the folder. I just want to check folder starting with "01-" and subfolder "Pictures". skip rest.

Answer (score 0):

```
for dirname in `find ./ -type d | grep Pictures`; do if [ $(find $dirname -type f|wc -l) -eq 0 ]; then echo "$dirname is empty"; fi; done
```

Replace find ./ with the find $RootDir for your search.